# reverting from derivative to base class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I've initialized an object '_currDie' in the Die class, ran an if statement to change the object to a derivative class object, then run a method.

The problem is that when it leaves the if statement, it seems to be reverting back to the base class.

```
namespace CharacterSheet
{
public partial class DiceRoller : Form
{        
     Die _currDie;
    public DiceRoller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void chooseSides_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D4")
        {
            D4 _currDie = new D4();
        }

        if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D6")
        {
            D6 _currDie = new D6();
        }

        if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D8")
        {
            D8 _currDie = new D8();
        }

        if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D10")
        {
            D10 _currDie = new D10();
        }

        if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D20")
        {
            D20 _currDie = new D20();
        }

        if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Percentile")
        {
            Percentile _currDie = new Percentile();
        }



    }


    private void Roll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _currDie.Roll();
        string currResult = Convert.ToString(_currDie.RollResult);

        MessageBox.Show(currResult);

    }



}
}
```

Here is the base class

```
namespace CharacterSheet
{
public class Die
{

    public int Sides { get; set; }

    private Random rng = new Random();

    public int rollResult;

    public int RollResult
    {
        get
        {
            return rollResult;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Roll()
    {
        rollResult = rng.Next(Sides) + 1;

    }


}
}
```

And the derivative class I've been testing with

```
namespace CharacterSheet
{
public class D4:Die
{
  public D4 ()
    {
        Sides = 4;
    }

}
}
```

I set break points at the first if statement and as I step through I can clearly see that _currDie changes from a D4 object to a Die object on the _currDie.Roll();
At which point I get a System.NullReferenceException

I've tried instantiating _currDie without defining the class, but then the method gets errors because there is no Roll method for the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In each of your `if` statements, you're declaring a new local variable, e.g.

```
if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D4")
{
    D4 _currDie = new D4();
}
```

That initializes the new `_currDie` variable, but then you hit the end of the block, and so it's useless. What you want to do is assign a new value to the *existing* field:

```
if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D4")
{
    _currDie = new D4();
}
```

Note the lack of the declaration here, because you're not trying to declare a new variable. You're *just* assigning a value to an existing variable.

As an aside, if nothing else you would be better off with a switch statement:

```
switch (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString())
{
    case "D4": _currDie = new D4(); break;
    case "D6": _currDie = new D6(); break;
    case "D20": _currDie = new D20(); break;
    ...
}
```

I'd personally do something slightly different, probably having a `Dictionary<string, Func<Die>>` but that's a different matter.

Comment: You type too fast I give up

Comment: I tried a switch statement at first but was running into a similar exception. Now that I know the problem was declaring a new local variable, I'll give that another try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your member variable _currentDie with scope variables in each if...

You define your _currDie member in your class, that's OK

```
public partial class DiceRoller : Form
{        
    Die _currDie; // define the die member, OK
    // <SNIP>
```

Then later on you create a new variable named __curDie (the compiler must be warning you about this check the output window)

```
    // _currDie means this._currdie
    if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D20")
    {
        D20 _currDie = new D20(); // you create a new variable named _currDie in this scope...
    } // the scope end so now __curdie means this.__curdie
```

The fix is quite simple:

```
    if (chooseSides.SelectedItem.ToString() == "D20")
    {
        _currDie = new D20(); // assign the value to the member __curDie
    }
```